# How to update data in json using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to update my json if uid = 0090000219 i want to change my `"secret"`

i have this json:

```
[
{
"id":23,
"uid":"0090000219",
"cid":"0090000013",
"extension":"201",
"secret":"Myojyo42_f",
"leader":true,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":17,
"created_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12",
"updated_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12"
},
{
"id":24,
"uid":"0090000221",
"cid":"0090000013",
"extension":"203",
"secret":"Myojyo42_f",
"leader":false,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":17,
"created_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12",
"updated_at":"2015-09-02 12:49:12"
},
{
"id":25,
"uid":"0090000220",
"cid":"0090000013",
"extension":"202",
"secret":"Myojyo42_f",
"leader":false,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":17,
"created_at":"2015-09-08 07:40:04",
"updated_at":"2015-09-08 07:40:04"
},
{
"id":26,
"uid":"0090000223",
"cid":"0090000013",
"extension":"205",
"secret":"Myojyo42_f",
"leader":false,
"simultaneous":false,
"confbridge_id":17,
"created_at":"2015-09-08 07:40:04",
"updated_at":"2015-09-08 07:40:04"
}
]
```

this is my code but it doesnt update:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var conf_url = "https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000013";
  getParticipant(conf_url, function(data){

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].uid == 0090000219) {
    data[i].secret = "Secret";
    break;
  }
}

alert("New secret: " + data[2].secret);
  });
     function getParticipant(conf_uri, handleData) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: conf_uri,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonpCallback: 'callback',
          contentType: "application/javascript",
          success: function(data) {
            handleData(data);
         //   console.log(data);
          }
        });

      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong value to check whether or not it succeeded.  You need to check the first object in the array, not the 3rd...

```
alert("New secret: " + data[0].secret);
```

Comment: hello @Archer . .thanks but i tried it . it doesnt work for me. . uhm

Comment: I just noticed - why are you alerting `data[2].secret`?  That's not the object you're modifying.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  Forget what I said about strings and integers - this is the problem.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help :)